# Test if environment variables inside a list exist (hush shell)

Tags: shell, unix

I've seen a ton of "how to test is an environment variable exists". And, it looks like the best answer is something like `[ -z ${var+x} ]`

That's all great, but what if I have a list of possible environment variables inside of a for loop like:

```
MY_LIST="a b c d e f g"
```

and I want to actually see if `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, etc., exist?  As in, were they set in the passed in environment.

Tried:

```
for i in $MY_LIST; do  
 if [ -z ${$i+x} ]; then  
  echo "doesn't exist"  
 else  
  echo "does exist"  
 fi  
done
```

to no avail.  What's the trick?  Note I'm in the hush shell.

Comment: You need to use indirect expansion.

Comment: ...which hush doesn't support (see its source at http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/hush.c). Any non-hacky answer will require using a real shell. That said, `eval` is available, so horrible awful hacks are probably feasible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use indirect expansion when the name of the variable is in another variable. You do this by putting `!` at the beginning of the variable name.

```
for i in $MY_LIST; do  
   if [ -z ${!i+x} ]; then  
      echo "doesn't exist"  
   else  
      echo "does exist"  
   fi  
done
```

Comment: Tried to no avail:  
#! /bin/sh
test="SHELL"
echo "shell is $SHELL, test is $test, and indirect of test is $!test"
#./d.sh
shell is /bin/sh, test is SHELL, and indirect of test is test
#

Comment: This should work in `bash`, which is how you tagged your question. I'm not famliar with `hush`, it looks like a very minimal shell, so it probably doesn't have this.

Comment: "Very minimal" is quite the understatement; hush doesn't even pretend to be compliant with POSIX sh.

Comment: It doesn't have `eval`, either. I don't think there's any way to do this without indirect variables or eval.

Comment: The copy I'm looking at (from the busybox master branch) has `eval`.

Comment: There was no "hush" tag, so I gave "bash" a shot as it is supposedly similar.  Can't believe someone took the "bash" tag off.  Goodness sakes...

Comment: @daveoman, I did, because hush is not at all similar to bash. Hush *wants to* be similar to Bourne shell (not 90s-era POSIX sh, but 70s-era Bourne), but it isn't even competent at that.

Comment: @daveoman, ...btw, could you check whether your particular copy of `hush` supports `eval`? If so, there's likely to be an answer possible -- not a pretty one, nor a robust one, but an answer. If not, you're likely to end up with "hush can't do that" (absent absurdities such as generating code into an external file and executing that).